# How to do Text file changes in a ZIP file in InstallShield Basic MSI project

Tags: installshield

How to do Text file changes in a ZIP file in InstallShield Basic MSI project. I am not able to do Text file changes in a file which is inside a zipped file.

Comment: What is your use case for this?  In 20 years I've never been asked to update a file within a zip file.

Comment: Use case: having a .xap file (silverlight compressed file) and a config file in it, I am somehow able to rename .xap to .zip (using power shell script), now I need to change the config file in it and rename it back to xap.

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield does not offer this capability, at least not now. You will have to either surround the call to the text-file-changing custom action with ones that extract and replace the zipped file (the text file changes would operate on the temporary copy), or implement the whole thing yourself in one step. I'm not sure which approach will be easier.

Comment: Personally I've never had anything like this request.  The closest was a request someone made to unpack a jar, modify a config setting and repack it.  I eliminated the requirement by suggesting a design change to the application.

Comment: Agreed; given the additional information you got from the asker, I wouldn't recommend the steps I gave in this answer. In unsigned cases, it's much less unreasonable, but still unusual.

Comment: One of the installers at my day job is a server side installer that deploys a website that hosts a Silverlight app.  We have a client side installer also that sets up some infrastructure to allow the XAP to run elevated out of browser.  We've done some config customizations like this question poses.  Why we didn't just write this as a WPF desktop app though is beyond me. (Sidenote: Silverlight is dead.) Some people (most developers I meet)  are just afraid of desktop deployment (even when they have me on staff)  and seem to think web is the solution to everything.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I would reframe the design and requirement.  Silverlight .XAP files are typically digitally signed.  Any attempt to modify the archive would invalidate this.  It's also needlessly complicated.

Instead, change your application to use an external configuration file.  native InstallShield functionality can then be used to update this file.  For a possible approach, see:

[Creating and Using Silverlight web.config app settings (Web.config Configuration Applicatioin Settings) or app.config application settings configuration file for Silverlight](http://www.mohamedibrahim.net/blog/2010/01/27/creating-and-using-silverlight-app-settings-webconfig-configuration-applicatioin-settings-to-change-wcf-service-address-after-deployment-servicereferencesclientconfig-servicereferences-clientconfig/)